# mariadb access denied to centreon@localhost

Tags: debian, mariadb

Im trying to migrate centreon to new server and version, i have this error in syslog on debian11.

```
mariadbd[1640]: 2023-10-20 11:13:52 13360 [Warning] Access denied for user 'centreon'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

I have try to grant privileges

```
hMariaDB [(none)]> SHOW GRANTS FOR 'centreon'@'localhost';
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for centreon@localhost                                                                                                                                                            |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO `centreon`@`localhost` IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '*xxx'                                                                          |
| GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, CREATE, DROP, REFERENCES, INDEX, ALTER, CREATE TEMPORARY TABLES, LOCK TABLES, CREATE VIEW, EVENT ON `centreon`.* TO `centreon`@`localhost`         |
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `mysql`.* TO `centreon`@`localhost`                                                                                                                              |
| GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, CREATE, DROP, REFERENCES, INDEX, ALTER, CREATE TEMPORARY TABLES, LOCK TABLES, CREATE VIEW, EVENT ON `centreon_storage`.* TO `centreon`@`localhost` |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
4 rows in set (0.000 sec)
```

But still i have this error, how can i fix it ?

Comment: Well, check that the credentials are correct?

Comment: I have checked with:
MariaDB [(none)]> SELECT user, host FROM mysql.user WHERE user = 'centreon' AND host = 'localhost' AND password = PASSWORD('password');
+----------+-----------+
| User     | Host      |
+----------+-----------+
| centreon | localhost |
+----------+-----------+
1 row in set (0.001 sec)

Comment: Please edit your question to add additional information. And please don't post screenshots of text you could just copy&paste, you are just making it harder to extract information out of it.

Comment: @RomeoNinov This are my database users: MariaDB [(none)]> select user from mysql.user;
+-------------+
| User        |
+-------------+
| centreon    |
| mariadb.sys |
| mysql       |
| root        |
+-------------+

Comment: @RAN55, insert text, not images. Images are not very helpful!

Comment: Note that in MySQL on *nix hosts the localhost  keyword is used exclusively for connections using the MySQL socket. You need to set up credentials for `'centreon'@'127.0.0.1'` when your application does not use the MySQL socket but is configured to make a TCP connection to localhost OR alternatively adjust the application to use the socket. Confusingly in TCP connections over 127.0.0.1 , a reverse DNS lookup is performed and 127.0.0.1 will be displayed as `localhost` even though the socket isn't used.

Comment: It was a password problem in a configuration file. Thanks for help.